# Physical Computing - making a switch

Tags: python, switches

I am following the physical computing with python tutorial from here: https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/physical-computing

I have created a python file that contains the following:

```
from gpiozero import LED, Button
from signal import pause

led = LED(17)
button = Button(2)

button.when_pressed = led.on
button.when_released = led.off

pause()
```

Also I have the button and led connected to the correct pins and in parallel. When I test the light and button separately directly in the command line, they work fine.

Also I get this message, but I don't know if that has anything to do with this issue:

```
/home/pi/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gpiozero/devices.py:451: PinFactoryFallback: Falling back from rpigpio: No module named RPi
  'Falling back from %s: %s' % (name, str(e))))
/home/pi/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gpiozero/devices.py:451: PinFactoryFallback: Falling back from rpio: No module named RPIO
  'Falling back from %s: %s' % (name, str(e))))
/home/pi/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gpiozero/devices.py:451: PinFactoryFallback: Falling back from pigpio: No module named pigpio
  'Falling back from %s: %s' % (name, str(e))))
```

Can someone please help?

Edit1: Ok, I have uninstalled gpiozero, and am left with the default version included for python3. What I am typing now in terminal is `python3 gpio_control.py` which includes the name of the file I posted. There isn't any output when I run it and it does not terminate. –

Edit2: I got this to work (light turns on when pressed and off when released) with the following code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
from gpiozero import LED, Button

led = LED(17)
button = Button(2)

while True:
        button.wait_for_press()
        led.on()
        button.when_released = led.off()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is lacking detail - **specifically WHAT you are ACTUALLY typing**.  The error suggests you are using Python2.7 and have manually installed `gpiozero` (which should be included in Raspbian), but AFAIK the examples are intended for Python3.

The "examples" strike me as **POOR Programming practice**

Even if you are running examples from `IDLE3` or `Thonny` there is **NO REASON** NOT to include  a shebang at the start of the program.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
```

Likewise there is **NO REASON** for new programs to be written in Python2.

Whatever you do you **NEED** to install and run for a specific version of Python.

Comment: Ok, I have uninstalled gpiozero, and am left with the default version included for python3.  What I am typing now in terminal is `python3 gpio_control.py` which includes the name of the file I posted. There isn't any output when I run it and it does not terminate.

Comment: @NicholasSchmidt You should post additional detail in your post, not Comments. The program ACTUALLY does nothing! I probably ran, You probably want to use  `button.wait_for_press()`, and unless you intend it to run once, include in a loop. (These were not the questions you asked.)